# Golang GAE - HTML Template not inserting links properly into web page

Tags: html, google-app-engine, parsing, templates, go

I am using Google Go on Google App Engine. I am saving a `string` description in a structure into a `datastore`, like so:

```
type Foo struct{
    Bar string
}
```

That description includes html tags, for example:

```
<a href="/">Bar</a>
```

I want the `html template` to include that description in an html file so it would be parsed as html. For example:

```
<html><head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>{{.Bar}}</body></html>
```

to be parsed as:

```
<html><head><title>Title</title></head>
<body><a href="/">Bar</a></body></html>
```

but instead, I get something like this:

```
<html><head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>&lt;a href=&#34;/&#34;&gt;Bar&#39;s&lt;/a&gt;</body></html>
```

How can I make the `template` parse the `string` correctly into an html link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `"http/template"` package automatically escapes all strings. To get around this you must make the value of type `template.HTML`. E.g.

```
import "html/template"

type Foo struct {
    Bar template.HTML
}
```

And then in your code do something like:

```
Foo.Bar = template.HTML(barString)
```

Comment: For the second part - `Foo["Bar"]` of `Foo.Bar`?

Comment: @ThePiachu Yes it should be `Foo.Bar`